# jQuery/Ajax request is being sent twice

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I've been scanning my code over and over again but I can't seem to find the problem.
When I click the link `#add-user-btn` the file `actions.php` is called twice (and hence the PHP script is executed twice).

Here's the script: I suppose it has something to do with the javascript in front of the ajax request?

```
$(function () {
    $("#add-user-btn").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var action = "adduser";

        $.ajax({
            url: '../actions.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: action,
                email: email,
                name: name,
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $(".close-reveal-modal").click();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="adduser" class="reveal-modal">
 <h1>Add new user</h1>
 <p><label for="email">E-mail:</label> <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="name@example.com" /></p>
 <p><label for="name">Name:</label> <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Adam Smith"/></p>
 <p><label for="password">Password:</label> <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="123456" /></p>
 <p>
 <label for="authorization">Authorization:</label> 
 <select id="authorization" name="authorization">
    <option value="0">Administrator</option>
    <option value="1">Superuser</option>
    <option value="2">User</option>
 </select>     
 </p>
 <button id="add-user-btn">Submit</button>
 <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with ID of `add-user-btn`, also, is `$(".close-reveal-modal").click();` this line re-triggering the request?

Comment: Are you sure you are not double clicking:)

Comment: Is the button inside a form? Does the page reload? How do you know it calls the PHP file twice?

Comment: Have you tried commenting out `$(".close-reveal-modal").click();`?  I would be curious if that has some affect.

Comment: I know because I check the XHR request in my browser's console. There is only one add-user-btn in my document. However there are multiple close-reveal-modal elements. Will tinker with that. 

The button is not inside of a form (it's just a link) and the page does not reload.

Comment: try logging the ajax call console.log(e.target) in beforesend event of ajax

Comment: I would really like to see this question looked at further to identify the root cause.  Any answer would then be much more useful to the community.

Comment: @Jenszor can you please post the HTML markup as well so we can figure out WHY this happened?

Comment: Added the HTML to the original question.
@Maikus, haven't tried commenting out that line of JS yet.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try

```
$("#add-user-btn").unbind('click').bind('click', function () { });
```

This will ensure the click event only gets called once.

Comment: We all guess a little from time to time, but there's absolutely nothing in the question to suggest this is the right answer, even if this approach often solves issues that should have been solved elsewhere.

Comment: This could solve an issue that is caused by some other error (but doesn't solve the error).  Both tymeJV and adeneo are correct.  I was a bit hasty in answering.

Comment: This solved it! Many thanks! I still have no idea what went wrong though.

Comment: Like all the others have been implying, you should try to figure out the underlying issue.  Does it submit twice every time?  Are you loading the elements using ajax?  The fact that the above works means that you don't have two elements with the same id and a form issue isn't causing your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This problem also occurs when you include multiple times the same JavaScript file in your HTML file.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="utility.js"></script>
        <script src="utility.js"></script>
    </head>
```

Comment: It depends on the browser implementation, but can happen indeed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533723/what-happens-if-you-use-a-script-tag-with-the-same-src-attribute-multiple-ti

Comment: @Alex Cristian R - love you man. surprisingly, it was my case. I thought I will get some specific errors if I do that. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When I worked with an specific website that I only had access to my javascript, I got this kind of error too. The problem was that there was lots of $(function() and $(document).ready in other codes.

what you can do to prevent this, if you can't correct the core problem is:

```
var preventRunDefault;
$(function () {
    if(!preventRunDefault) {
    preventRunDefault = true;
    $("#add-user-btn").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var action = "adduser";

        $.ajax({
            url: '../actions.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: action,
                email: email,
                name: name,
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $(".close-reveal-modal").click();
            }
        });
    });
   }
});
```

But the right way is to search the cause and don't do workarounds.