# AJAX call being sent twice from HTML form

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple HTML form which is linked to a jQuery function which sends data to a PHP script. The issue is that the ajax call is being sent twice. I was initially alerted to this when I saw that 2 identical entries were going into the database. I switched to firebug and sure enough - 2 POST requests sent and 2 GET callbacks both identical. I have looked around stack for an answer and did find one seemingly identical problem but that answer suggested using bind and unbind in the function without a clear explanation why the problem exists. I thought the hidden submit button might be an issue but if I comment this out - same problem. There are a number of tumbleweed questions which are very similar to mine. Any help would be appreciated....

HTML FORM

```
          <form action="" method="post">
                  <table>   
                        <tr> 
                            <td>                          
                                <img class="profile_picture_mail" src="../<?php echo grab_thread_thumbnail($id); ?>">
                            </td>
                            <td>  
                            <input id="message_subject" name="subject" type="text" 
                            placeholder="Message subject" size="20"  maxlength="3000" value=""/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>                        
                  </table>
                  <table>
                        <tr> 
                            <td>        
                            <textarea id="message_field" name="message" type="text" placeholder="Message details"></textarea>                               
                            </td>
                        </tr>      
                  </table>
                <input id="submit_message" type="button" name="submit" value="send message" />              
                <input id="profile_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id;?>"/>           
           </form>
```

jQUERY

```
      $(document.body).on("click", "#submit_message", function(){
         var recipientId = $('#profile_id').val();
            $.ajax({
              url: '../ajax/insert_message.php',
              type: 'post',
              data: {
                 'subject': $('#message_subject').val(),
                 'message': $('#message_field').val(),
                 'recipientId': recipientId,
                   },
                  success: function(html) {

                         $('.reveal-modal-mail').load('message_box.php', {id: recipientId});
                         $('input[type="text"],text').val('');
                         $('input[type="text"],textarea').val('');
                          }
                    });
             return false;
              });
```

EDIT: I changed the id of the submit button to id="submit_a_message" and the problem was solved. I assume this means I have an extra submit button with the same id somewhere, although for the life of my I cannot find it. If I am wrong in my assumption as to why this worked, let me know. Keen to get to the bottom of this....

Comment: what your message_box.php is returning?

Comment: It's only sending one request for me. Will need more code related to this to locate the issue.

Comment: i have made some progress - not sure I fully understand how this solved it but see above

Comment: Try something like `console.log($("form"))` to find all forms. Hopefully, you will find your duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could solve your problem: [jQuery/Ajax request is being sent twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866972/jquery-ajax-request-is-being-sent-twice). They say you could try

```
$("#submit_message").unbind('click').bind('click', function () { });
```